# How to create multiple class objects and pass arguments with loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, constructor

Here is the set of data,

```
obj = [[A, B, 2], [D, A, 5] ,[B, C, 3]]
```

I would like to store this in the following class object

```
class Map():
 def __init__(self,start,destination,cost):
        self.start = start
        self.destination = destination
        self.cost = cost
```

I would like to store the obj in something like below with for loop

```
obj[0].start = A
obj[0].destination = B
obj[0].cost = 2
....
obj[2].start = B
obj[2].destination = C
obj[2].cost = 3
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension will do the trick.

```
obj = [Map(x, y, z) for x, y, z in obj]
```

You iterate over the original list, unpack each sublist, then call `Map` on each set of values.

Even simpler, you can let Python unpack the sublists for you.

```
obj = [Map(*args) for args in obj]
```

or

```
import itertools
obj = list(itertools.starmap(Map, obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list:

```
maps = []
for object in obj:
    maps.append(Map(object[0], object[1], object[2]))
```